# How to use string variable in survival analysis in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, r-factor

I wish to apply parametric survival analysis in R. My data is Veteran's lung cancer study data. Here is the first 20 column of the data:

[image]

I guess I need to convert `celltype` in to categorical dummy variables as lecture notes suggest here:

[image]

Firstty, I am wondering if there is any way to use the `celltype` as in the original form. If so, how?

Secondly, how can I create the dummy variables mentioned above?

Here is how you get the whole data:

```
library(survival)
veteran
```

and here is how the model was fitted in R:

```
weibull <- survreg(S ~c2 + c3 + c4, dist="w")
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a model matrix containing the 4 dummy variables for `celltype` with `model.matrix`:

```
model.matrix( ~ 0 + celltype, veteran)
```

The result:

```
    celltypesquamous celltypesmallcell celltypeadeno celltypelarge
1                  1                 0             0             0
2                  1                 0             0             0
3                  1                 0             0             0
4                  1                 0             0             0
5                  1                 0             0             0
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything special. Just enter that variable name in the formula. (I'm not impressed with the R programming abilities of your instructor if that was what you were taught):

```
> weibull <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~celltype, dist="w", data=veteran)
> weibull
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ celltype, data = veteran, 
    dist = "w")

Coefficients:
      (Intercept) celltypesmallcell     celltypeadeno     celltypelarge 
        5.4065502        -1.0831923        -1.2162022        -0.2627843 

Scale= 1.03048 

Loglik(model)= -734.2   Loglik(intercept only)= -748.1
    Chisq= 27.87 on 3 degrees of freedom, p= 3.9e-06 
n= 137
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but your output is different from the one in my lecture notes. What do you think is different? I have put the output into my post above.

Comment: Looks like pretty similar output to me. Only the `(Intercept)` parameter is different and the inferential statistics are all the same. You never showed how that `S` object was created so you are really asking us to read your mind now.

Comment: That is because S was not given in the lecture notes. Having looked at the data, I thought S = Surv(time,status). Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

To change factors you can use the following code:

```
DataFrame$celltype[DataFrame$celltype == "large"] <- 1
```

with this code you can change every part of your dataframe. Keep in mind that you have to change mode of the value from factor to numeric if you want to calculate something

```
DataFrame$celltype <- as.numeric(DataFrame$celltype)
```

best paj

PS: I am not sure if this was the question